Movie about rich boy whose father dies and he becomes a vigilante
There is a movie I once read about that I am trying to find.
There is the protagonist, whose father dies. The father was rich so it all goes to the protagonist. The boy and his driver (I think he was asian) become vigilantes. There was a girl, one of the two falls for her. She might have been a journalist. They create a facade for the vigilante. I don't remember the ending. The title might have had something to do with 'hero'.
The film was not extremely popular (say - batman level of popularity), but might have been well received. It is a film from 2000+.

Ok, just figured it out. The title is 'The green hornet'
I had some of the facts twisted a bit, but anyway.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
